# Regex: Binary string contains at least 3 of a certain integer

Tags: regex

I am working with regular expressions for a class and we need to have it set up to contain at least 3 0 throughout the string. BUT they don't need to be next to each other, so 101010 would pass but 101011 would fail because it lacks a 0.
`^[0-1]*(?:0){3,}[0-1]*$`
This is what I currently have but that requires them to be adjacent.

Comment: Hint: `^[01]*0[01]*0[01]*0[01]$`

Comment: Maybe `(?=^[01]+$)(?=.*?0.*?0.*?0)` what language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: We aren't programming with it currently we are just finishing with DFA and now we are transitioning to generalized regex. We have to test our stuff with regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
([01]*0[01]*){3}
```

The 0 in the center without a qualifier ensures that it exists at least 3 times in your string. The [01]* on either side requires a 0 or 1 zero to unlimited times, giving it some wiggle room so as not to require that the 3 zeros occur consecutively.
([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uKj8EF/1)) ([regexr.com](http://regexr.com/5ljui))